# Не могу данные из формы django передать в excel файл

Tags: python, django, excel

Суть задачи заключается в том , что из бд в форму погружаются данные и после выбора передать в excel файл. У меня не получается выдает ошибку object of type 'Price_Dipos' has no len() во view.py в строке "for col_num in range(len(row)):", пробовал по разному записывать не получается , может  я что то не понимаю, не знаю, помогите пожалуйста.
model.py

```
  from django.db import models
class Price_Dipos(models.Model):

id_v1_dipos = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Название изделия")
cost = models.IntegerField()
objects = models.Manager()
def __str__(self):
    return"{0} {1} {2}".format(self.id_v1_dipos,self.name,self.cost)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Price_Dipos ,Price_SevZap, Price_MelallServ
class Prise_Dipos_Form(forms.Form):
    name = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset= Price_Dipos.objects.all())
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Price_Dipos ,Price_SevZap, Price_MelallServ
from .forms import Prise_Dipos_Form
import xlwt

def index(request):

    num_books=Price_Dipos.objects.all()
    num_books1=Price_SevZap.objects.all()
    num_books2=Price_MelallServ.objects.all()

    form = Prise_Dipos_Form(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
        wd = xlwt
        wb = xlwt.Workbook()
        ws = wb.add_sheet('Test')
        row_num = 0
        font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
        font_style.font.bold =True

        columns = ['name']

        for col_num in range(len(columns)):
            ws.write(row_num,col_num, columns[col_num], font_style)


        font_style =xlwt.XFStyle()

        rows = name
        for row in rows:
            row_num += 1
            for col_num in range(len(row)):
                ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], font_style)


        wb.save('test.xls') 
    else:
        form = Prise_Dipos_Form()


    return render(
        request,
        'index.html',
        context={'form': form},
    )
```

Comment: rows = name вот тут посмотри

Comment: так понял ,что тут а что именно должно быть я вот не понимаю этого

Comment: ну посмотри, что у тебя в `row`